# XML delimiters in C#

Tags: c#

I am having a XML file to be read line by line. But while I am executing I am getting this error "The class $Classname$ must be marked with the [DelimitedRecord] or [FixedLengthRecord] Attribute." But for an XML file how to set delimiters. In my code I am also executing Flat files and CSV file too. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Do you use a special library to read the file? Why don't you read the file using XDocumemt or XmlDocument? If you have to read it line by line as text, you could also use a StreamReader or File.Read(All)Lines.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you receive, I suspect that you use the FileHelpers library. This library helps you in parsing CSV-files and others. I don't know whether it also supports Xml. But as Xml is a very widely spread, the .NET Framework provides support for reading and parsing Xml files. Have a look at Linq to Xml ([XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx)) or the DOM implementation ([XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)), if you are interested in reading and parsing the content of an Xml file.

If you are only interested in reading the file line by line without parsing/interpreting the contents, a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) or the [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method can do the job.